# How to move to other action method on button click in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I made a form where user can enter all details. Like a fill up form. After filling up form. When user click on Save button it should be automatically move to other action method in same controller. And must show data in GRID VIEW in MVC. Where in grid view user can update and save all data which he entered while filling up the form. 
I used DB first approach. And make a view model class. Here is the code of View Model class.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Prodcut Name")]
    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Choose Category")]
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Price")]
    [DisplayName("Enter Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Picture")]
    [DisplayName("Choose Picture")]
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choos Country")]
    public Nullable<int> Country_ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose Type")]
    [DisplayName("Choose Product Type")]
    public string Product_Type { get; set; }
    public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Code

```
ProductionEntities DBContext = new ProductionEntities(); 

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

    List<tblCategory> CategoryList = DBContext.tblCategories.ToList();
    model.CategoryList = new SelectList(CategoryList, "Category_ID", "Category_Name");

    List<tblCountry> CountryList = DBContext.tblCountries.ToList();
    model.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "Country_ID", "Country_Name");
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    //ViewModel v = new ViewModel();
    //if (image1!=null)
    //{
    //    model.Picture = new byte[image1.ContentLength];
    //    image1.InputStream.Read(model.Picture, 0, image1.ContentLength);
    //}

    List<tblCategory> CategoryList = DBContext.tblCategories.ToList();
    model.CategoryList = new SelectList(CategoryList, "Category_ID", "Category_Name");
    List<tblCountry> CountryList = DBContext.tblCountries.ToList();
    model.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "Country_ID", "Country_Name");
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        tblProduct product = new tblProduct();
        product.Category_ID = model.SelectedValue;
        product.Country_ID = model.Country_ID;
        product.Price = model.Price;
        product.Product_Name = model.Product_Name;
        product.Date = model.Date;
        product.Picture = model.Picture;
        product.Product_Type = model.Product_Type;
        try
        {
            DBContext.tblProducts.Add(product);
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch  (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow P-R-G (**Post-Redirect-Get**) pattern. After successfully saving the record, send a redirect response to the browser which will issue a totally new GET request to the action method which renders the tabular data.

```
DBContext.tblProducts.Add(product);
DBContext.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("List");
```

and in your `List` action method you will read the records needed for the tabular data and render it in it's view.

Comment: After data is saved in DB. When user click on Save button. It should automatically move to other action(Next Page/View) with all data he entered and data must be in grid view(Populate). Where he can edit or update his data.

Comment: The redirect will make the browser to issue a new GET request to the List action where you have to write code to read the data needed to display and render it. No one will write code for your full requirement.